# Variable substitution with an exclamation mark in bash

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I have the following lines in my .cfg bash script file

```
DDF_SOURCE="siebel_DATA_DATE_FORMAT"
DATA_DATE_FORMAT=${!DDF_SOURCE}
```

how is `${!DDF_SOURCE`} evaluated? It would be `!siebel_DATA_DATE_FORMAT`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

That is an *indirect expansion*, documented in `man bash` section *EXPANSION*, subsection *Parameter Expansion*:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. 
>   This is known as indirect expansion.

```
bash-4.2$ DDF_SOURCE="siebel_DATA_DATE_FORMAT"

bash-4.2$ siebel_DATA_DATE_FORMAT='Hello Indirect Redirection'

bash-4.2$ DATA_DATE_FORMAT=${!DDF_SOURCE} # siebel_DATA_DATE_FORMAT must get value before this line

bash-4.2$ echo $DATA_DATE_FORMAT
Hello Indirect Redirection
```