# bash dynamic (variable) variable names

Tags: bash, variable

I want to dynamically create a sequence of strings by manipulate an array of elements and create some arithmetic procedure.

```
for name in FIRST SECOND THIRD FOURTH FIFTH; do
    $name = $(( $6 + 1 ))
    $name = "${$name}q;d"
    echo "${$name}"; printf "\n"
done
```

The desire outcome would be the below for `$6` equals `0`.

```
1q;d
2q;d
3q;d
4q;d
5q;d
```

But I get this error

```
reel_first_part.sh: line 18: FIRST: command not found
reel_first_part.sh: line 19: ${$name}q;d: bad substitution
reel_first_part.sh: line 18: FIRST: command not found
reel_first_part.sh: line 19: ${$name}q;d: bad substitution
reel_first_part.sh: line 18: FIRST: command not found
reel_first_part.sh: line 19: ${$name}q;d: bad substitution
```

I guess it's something simple. It used to work when I did something like

```
FIRST=$(( $6 + 1 ))
FIRST="${FIRST}q;d"
```

Comment: Can you explain it little better. Don't really understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: What is  ` $name = $(( $6 + 1 ))` supposed to do?

Comment: @PSkocik I was hoping to do `FIRST=$(( $6 + 1 ))`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all there can not be any space around `=` in variable declaration in `bash`.

To get what you want you can use `eval`.

For example a sample script like yours :

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for name in FIRST SECOND THIRD FOURTH FIFTH; do
    eval "$name"="'$(( $i + 1 ))q;d'"
    printf '%s\n' "${!name}"
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

Prints :

```
1q;d
2q;d
3q;d
4q;d
5q;d
```

Use `eval` cautiously, some people call it evil for some valid reason.

`declare` would work too :

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for name in FIRST SECOND THIRD FOURTH FIFTH; do
    declare "$name"="$(( $i + 1 ))q;d"
    printf '%s\n' "${!name}"
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

also prints :

```
1q;d
2q;d
3q;d
4q;d
5q;d
```

Comment: What is the `!` exclamation mark `printf '%s\n' "${!name}"` for?

Comment: Its called indirect expansion of `bash` parameter expansion..read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41293/68757)

Comment: Bash also has a nicer alternative to `declare` / `eval`: `printf -v varname '%fmt' args`.  Some bash-completion internal functions use this for call-by-reference.  (pass the name of a variable to store into).

Comment: Note: Using `declare` only sets the variable in the local scope, while the `eval` approach sets it globally.

Comment: AFAIK, the `eval` solution is the only POSIX compliant one.

Comment: @user `declare` has flag `-g` to declare variable to be a global.

Answer (score 41):

If you want to reference a bash variable while having the name stored in another variable you can do it as follows:

```
$ var1=hello
$ var2=var1
$ echo ${!var2}
hello
```

You store the name of the variable you want to access in, say, var2 in this case.  Then you access it with `${!<varable name>}` where `<variable name>` is a variable holding the name of the variable you want to access.

Comment: There is portable way with `eval var=\$$holder` but `eval` is dangerous!

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. This should be the accepted answer, since it does not use `eval` and since the OP specifically has asked for bash, so portability is not an issue. However, to read more details about it in the bash manual and to be able to find the respective section, how is this construct / method called?

Comment: Great answer! Upvoted. I expounded upon your answer with additional insight and explanation, and added an "equivalent" example using the "evil" `eval`, in my answer I just added here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222487/bash-dynamic-variable-variable-names/631737#631737.

Comment: The `${!var_name}` doesn't work in BusyBox ash and dash so the `eval var_val=\$$var_name` is the only cross platform syntax :(

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev Sure, but those are not `bash`, and this question specifically asks about bash.  Using `eval` will always be risky if processing user supplied values, but perhaps there are situations where that will be a suitable approach

Answer (score 10):

I just want to show a slightly more-thorough version of [Eric Renouf's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222586/114401) to make it crystal clear how you can dynamically generate a variable name **from *multiple* other variables** and then access the contents of that new, dynamically-generated variable.

```bash
some_variable="Hey how are you?"

# the 1st half of the variable name "some_variable"
var1="some"
# the 2nd half of the variable name
var2="variable"

# dynamically recreate the variable name "some_variable", stored
# as a string inside variable `var3`
var3="${var1}_${var2}"
```

Now look at these outputs:

```bash
echo "${var3}"
```

outputs:

> ```bash
> some_variable
> ```

BUT this (the *exact same as above* except we added the `!` char just before the variable name is all):

```bash
echo "${!var3}"
```

outputs:

> ```bash
> Hey how are you?
> ```

It's magical!

It's *as though* we had a C macro where we had `echo "${${var3}}"` which expanded to `echo "${some_variable}"` which then became `Hey how are you?`.

That syntax would be invalid, however, and you'd get this error:

```bash
$ echo "${${var3}}"
bash: ${${var3}}: bad substitution
```

You can do this `echo "${!var3}"` trick in place of using `eval`, since `eval` is considered "dangerous" and "evil". For understanding and education though, **here is the equivalent way to do this with `eval` instead**:

```bash
$ eval echo "\$${var3}"
Hey how are you?
```

versus:

```bash
$ echo "${!var3}"
Hey how are you?
```

`eval echo "\$${var3}"` expands to `eval echo "$some_variable"`, which has the same output:

```bash
$ eval echo "$some_variable"
Hey how are you?
```

But, even though `eval echo "\$${var3}"` and `echo "${!var3}"` produce the *exact same result* in this case (the `Hey how are you?` output), apparently the `eval` version is evil and the `!` version is good.

You can read the "good" version (`echo "${!var3}"`) as follows (in my own words):

> echoing `"$var3"` means: "output the contents of the `var3` variable." BUT, echoing `"${!var3}"` means: "output the contents of what the `var3` variable contains, assuming *its contents* are the *name to another variable*!"

The `!` in bash here is *kind of* like dereferencing a pointer in C with the `*` character like this!:

```bash
*some_ptr
```

It adds an extra layer of abstraction.

### Related

1. Note that the need for this `!` trick can frequently be avoided using *associative arrays* in bash. Associative arrays are essentially "hash tables", which are called "unordered maps" in C++ and "dicts" (dictionaries) in Python. Here are a few relevant links on them:

   1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149679/multidimensional-associative-arrays-in-bash
   2. [VERY GOOD TUTORIAL!] *****https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/

   Keep in mind, however, that associative arrays (and all other arrays too) in bash are *1-dimensional*! From `man 1 bash` (emphasis added):

   > Arrays
   >
   > Bash  provides **one-dimensional** *indexed* and *associative* array variables.  Any variable may be
   > used as an indexed array; the declare builtin will explicitly declare an array.  There is no
   > maximum  limit  on  the  size  of  an  array, nor any requirement that members be indexed or
   > assigned contiguously.  Indexed arrays are referenced using integers  (including  arithmetic
   > expressions)  and are zero-based; associative arrays are referenced using arbitrary strings.
   > Unless otherwise noted, indexed array indices must be non-negative integers.
   >
   > An indexed array is created automatically if any variable is assigned to  using  the  syntax
   > name[subscript]=value.  The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must eval‐
   > uate to a number.  To explicitly declare an indexed array, use declare -a  name  (see  SHELL
   > BUILTIN  COMMANDS  below).   declare  -a  name[subscript] is also accepted; the subscript is
   > ignored.
   >
   > Associative arrays are created using declare -A name.
   >
   > Attributes may be specified for an array variable using the declare and  readonly  builtins.
   > Each attribute applies to all members of an array.
   >
   > Arrays  are  assigned  to  using  compound assignments of the form name=(value1 ... valuen),
   > where each value is of the  form  [subscript]=string.   Indexed  array  assignments  do  not
   > require anything but string.  When assigning to indexed arrays, if the optional brackets and
   > subscript are supplied, that index is assigned  to;  otherwise  the  index  of  the  element
   > assigned is the last index assigned to by the statement plus one.  Indexing starts at zero.
   >
   > When assigning to an associative array, the subscript is required.

Comment: Which approach would you recommend with shell? As `${!<varable name>}` is not supported by shell.

Comment: @Freddy, `eval echo "\$${var3}"` works fine in the `sh` shell. Or, does your system have `bash`? Type in `bash --version` at the command-line. If it returns with a version number, you have `bash`. Add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to the top of your bash script, like I do in [eRCaGuy_hello_world/bash/hello_world_basic.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/hello_world_basic.sh), to force that script to use `bash`, and then use `echo "${!var3}"` instead.

Comment: I though maybe there is a way to avoid `eval` in `sh` shell but then `eval echo "\$${var3}"`  it is.

Comment: @Freddy, if you post it as a question, put a link back here so I can follow the question too, but I don't think there's another way in `sh`, but I'm no expert on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

What I get from your code and your desired output (correct me if I'm wrong):
There is no use of the "FIRST"/"SECOND"/... variable names, you just need a loop with an index...

This will do the job:

`for i in {1..5} ; do echo $i"q;d" ; done`

Comment: Yes, you are right, except additionally I want to do an arithmetic function with a variable.

Comment: Can you give an example of this arithmetic function? Do you need the variable name (like "THIRD") for it or just the index value?

Comment: `SUM=$(($6 + $i)); echo $SUM"q;d"`, I see what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
index=0;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
for name in FIRST SECOND THIRD FOURTH FIFTH; do
    name=$(($index + 1))
    echo "${name}q;d"
    index=$((index+1))
done
```

Is that what you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a response here as I don't think the most upvoted solution really represents a correct answer to the problem, and the accepted solution could lead to unexpected behavior, e.g.

```
desired_var_name="echo hello ace! && x"
eval $desired_var_name=value
```

You should use the `declare` command, e.g.

```
desired_var_name="myvar"
desired_value=assiged
declare $desired_var_name=$desired_value
```

Now,

```
echo $myvar
```

outputs

```
assiged
```

Comment: Well, you have presented ***an*** example of how ``eval`` can be dangerous.  The accepted answer says that `eval` is dangerous, and this is documented widely, along with the warning that you shouldn’t, for example, allow a (possibly hostile or malicious) user specify a string that will be used in an `eval` statement without checking it *thoroughly.* The accepted answer also shows `declare`, so you don’t seem to be adding a lot of new information.

Comment: This answer helped me more than the accepted answer because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I develop a text based non-interactive randomized fighting game script (where the fight plays out like an old style MUD). My latest innovation is to use arrays to store the active fighters and or items during a battle. This is the method I worked out to create and utilize dynamic arrays that can be referenced from the main 'actors' array. The following is my proof of concept code that I've been working out. The part that may help you is down where the arrays get created and populated:

```
    # action line:
my_name (eg. johnny cage) uses obj_name (eg. duck)

    # 'duck' item details:
obj=duck.s.2.3
obj_name=$(echo "$item" | cut -d. -f1)
obj_type=$(echo "$item" | cut -d. -f2)
obj_min=$(echo "$item" | cut -d. -f3)
obj_max=$(echo "$item" | cut -d. -f4)
if obj_type="a" (actor) then they can use items:
obj_useitems=1
else it cant use items:
obj_useitems=0
obj_owner="$my_name"
if obj_name="duck" then set a delay before it attacks:
obj_delay=$(( (RANDOM % 6) + 6 ))
obj_id=$(( ${#actors[@]} + 1 ))

    # if it's an actor (eg. if obj_name="duck" or obj_type="a"), add to the array of actors that exist:
actors+=( "$obj_name.$obj_id" )

    # create the object array for the item / actor with all its/their stats:
declare -A new_obj=( [name]=$obj_name [type]=$obj_type [min]=$obj_min [max]=$obj_max [id]=$obj_id [use items]=$obj_useitems [owner]=$obj_owner [active]=$obj_delay )
    # create the dynamic named array with the object's id:
declare -A obj_$obj_id
    # assign the new_obj values to the dynamic array:
    eval obj_$obj_id[name]="\${new_obj[name]}"; eval obj_$obj_id[type]="\${new_obj[type]}"; eval obj_$obj_id[min]="\${new_obj[min]}"
    eval obj_$obj_id[max]="\${new_obj[max]}";eval obj_$obj_id[id]="\${new_obj[id]}";eval obj_$obj_id[life]="\${new_obj[life]}"
    eval obj_$obj_id[use items]="\${new_obj[use items]}"; eval obj_$obj_id[owner]="\${new_obj[owner]}"; eval obj_$obj_id[active]="\${new_obj[active]}"
    
# loop through list of actors, and retrieve values from their associated dynamic array that contains all of their stats:

for actor in "${actors[@]}"; do
    actor_name=$(echo "$actor" | cut -d. -f1)
    actor_id=$(echo "$actor" | cut -d. -f2)
    if [[ $(eval echo \${obj_$actor_id[type]}) = "s" ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
done
```