# What does `echo ${!a}` do and why?

Tags: bash, echo, history-expansion

The following bash script prints out `c`, but I'm not sure why.

```bsh
a=b
b=c
echo ${!a}
```

I believe that `!a` will be converted to the last command which began with `a`, so in this case that would be `a=b`. This should mean that the last command is equivalent to the following.

```bsh
echo ${a=b}
```

However, that prints `b`, not `c`. Is anyone able to explain why this is the case?

Comment: related if not duplicated https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41406/72456

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41292/315749

Comment: @fra-san thanks that answers my question